# sudo - impersonating a user

Tags: sudo, users

I am trying to use the sudo command and sudoers file correctly so that I can run a command as another user.

I have my sudoers file set up as follows:

```
beans ALL = (root,apache) NOPASSWD: /opt/renovations/var/script-*.sh
```

root, apache, and beans are part of the group beans.
Also /opt has 755 permissions, while the /opt/renovations directory and it's sub-directories are owned by the beans user and group.

The command I'm trying to run as beans is:

```
sudo -n -u apache -i /opt/renovations/var/script-test.sh
```

-n: is so that I'm not prompted for a password, as this will be run by a cron
-u: is so that I can impersonate the apache user
-i: is so that I simulate a login, and my .profile is loaded. I need this so that I access the environment variables in .profile.

The problem is that when I run the sudo command, I get the following message:

> sudo: sorry, a password is required to run sudo

I've tried running this both on AIX and Ubuntu, but the problem is on both systems.  This works if I run:

```
sudo -n -u apache /opt/renovations/var/script-test.sh
```

But without the -i, my environment does not contain all of the environment variables that I need to be there.

Is there something I need to update in my sudoers file so that this is possible?

Comment: What does `visudo -c` return (checks sudoers for errors).  Also, can you confirm the full version of AIX (`oslevel -s`) and the version of sudo installed?

Comment: Also, does it work if you list the script name explicitly in sudo rather than the wildcard (and is the filename a symbolic link?).

Comment: Thanks @EightBitTone. So I found solution for this sudoers configuration issue: when -i switch is in use then real command is 

`beans ALL = (root,apache) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/ksh -c /opt/renovations/var/script-*.sh`
 and 
`beans ALL = (root,apache) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/bash -c /opt/renovations/var/script-*.sh`
But now I get the new error, for example: `ksh: /opt/renovations/var/script-test.sh: cannot execute`

Comment: Analysing the /var/log/sudolog log file was very helpful to debug above issue (on AIX).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So as you said yourself @krzysto, the solution is to add the following to the sudoers file

```
beans ALL = (root,apache) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/ksh -c /opt/renovations/var/script-*.sh 
beans ALL = (root,apache) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/bash -c /opt/renovations/var/script-*.sh
```

The next piece that is missing is to make sure that the group has execute permissions on the scripts, so that you can execute them.

Comment: yes, it is correct solution.  
The ksh error happens only on testing environment created for investigating the impersonation issue; in real, production all works correctly